# SAGA tool is showing issues or it is not competible in QGIS 3.16.11 LTR

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-processing, saga

I have installed in my Windows QGIS 3.16.11 LTR and wanted to use some of the function from SAGA tools, when I open the function it is telling that the SAGA officially does not support for this version of QGIS.

[image]

Comment: I think the question was not correctly edited @Taras. In Saga neither Snap points to line nor other tools are working. This photo is just an example for the message that comes from SAGA when you click any of the tools.

Comment: I get the same error message with my 3.2.  It's because I have both 2.3 and 7.8  installed in the OSGeo4W folder.  There are at least two plugins that would enable use of 7x, the SAGA for Processing and Processing SAGA Next Gen.  Despite the error message I have been able to use the SAGA tools, but I could use the SAGA GUI if there is a problem.  I recall there is a proposal to drop installing SAGA as part of QGIS's install and making it only a plugin due to problems supporting each new version of SAGA in a base install.